# Gale Shapley matching algorithm with fairness

Tags: algorithm, matching, theory

(sorry for the poor english)

Hi, I'm trying to implement [Gale, Shapley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) algorithm to different sized groups. I found a trick that consisted to duplicate "offers" for a given man (ie: a man's preferences is repeated in the men's preference list) and this second offer is added in women's lists.

example:
Let men be {1,2} and women {3,4}, I want some of the men to have more than one marriage (let 1 be this lucky/unlucky guy)
From the start the preferences lists of men is:
1:[3,4]
2:[4,3]
the preferences lists of women is:
3:[2,1]
4:[1,2]
It is a one-to-one matching problem.

To handle the case of polygamy, I follow the trick.
I can create a man 1' which hold the second offer of man 1 and has the same preference as 1
1':[3,4]
and I update women's list to add 1':
3:[2,1,1']
4:[1,1',2]
It becomes a many-to-one matching problem.

However it's now possible to one man (1) to get two mariages while another is still single. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rank all of the duplicates below all of the non-duplicates, then Gale–Shapley should match everyone, e.g., 3:[2,1,1'] and 4:[1,2,1']. The reasoning is that no woman will reject a proposal from a non-duplicate man if she's matched with a duplicate man, hence all non-duplicate men will be matched.